# Rails 4 routing: using namespaces with dynamic segments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

When discussing Routing using Dynamic Segments, the Ruby on Rails Guides (v4.0.1) say "*You can't use :namespace or :module with a :controller path segment.*" They go on to suggest: "*if you need to do this then use a constraint on :controller that matches the namespace you require*."

I've got a lot of controllers under quite a few namespaces. If I could get dynamic segments to work in my situation then I could handle all of that routing with one line in routes.rb. Perhaps something like this:

```
get '/:namespace/:controller/:action'             #note: this isn't valid
```

But that won't work (see above). I'd rather keep the namespaces, so I could just write out a fresh line in my *routes.rb* file for each namespace and then add a constraint to check that the URL is asking for that namespace. That wouldn't be the end of the world. It just seems so un-DRY and a shame because all the routing information is neatly presented right there in the URL.

I'm just wondering if there are any sneaky ways round what seems (to me) like a bit of a gap in the capabilities of Dynamic Segment Routing. Can one get the Routing DSL to run a block that (unlike Constraints) does something more complex than a Boolean yes/no on whether the route matches? Or perhaps I'm missing something in the way the standard Rails routing capabilities work. Any suggestions appreciated.

Update: Just to spell it out a little bit more. My understanding of the Rails Guides is that I'll need to have lines like these:

```
post ':controller/:action' , controller: /user_details\/[^\/]+/
post ':controller/:action' , controller: /preferences\/[^\/]+/
```

...and so on. If I want 20 namespaces then I'll need 20 of these lines. I'm just wondering if there isn't a more concise way that approaches my 1-line ideal given above.

Comment: So you're looking to "DRY" up your routes.rb file?

Comment: Added an update just to explain a little more what my 'DRY' goal is here, assuming it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a dynamic route that matches all routes like

```
post 'user_details/name/edit'     => 'user_details/name#edit'
post 'user_details/address/edit'  => 'user_details/address#edit'
post 'user_details/password/edit' => 'user_details/password#edit'
post 'preferences/privacy/edit'   => 'preferences/privacy#edit'
post 'preferences/colors/edit'    => 'preferences/colors#edit'
```

then you could just use

```
post ':controller/:action'
```

since the `:controller` part will match namespaced controllers, too.

Verified for Rails 4.0.1 and 4.2.0.

Comment: A word of caution: If you use dynamic routes, make sure you do not accidentally expose methods of your controller that are not actions.
Note that every public method in your controllers will be interpreted as action method! Declare any helper methods as `private`.